# Require First and Last Name on Comments in Drupal 7

Tags: comments

I enabled Comments on a content block in Drupal 7. I would like to have First and Last Name required on the comments. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, Comment fields are managed the same way Node fields are managed.

Go to structure->Content types-> edit link. If comment is enabled for selected content type, It will add a tab for "comment fields" on top besides manage fields tab.

For article content type url will be "admin/structure/types/manage/article/comment/fields" and tab looks like the image attached below.

[image]